# PHP code is working, but doesn't show who is the sender. Just showing noreply@example.com

Tags: php

My PHP code for sending email its working good, but there is a problem that doesn't show who is the sender just show noreply@example.com. I hosted my website at ecowebhosting.

```
<?php

 $error = "";
 $successMessage = "";
    if ($_POST) {        
        if (!$_POST["email"]) {            
            $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";            
        }        
        if (!$_POST["message"]) {            
            $error .= "The message field is required.<br>";            
        }        
        if (!$_POST["subject"]) {            
            $error .= "The subject is required.<br>";            
        }        
        if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {            
            $error .= "The email address is invalid.<br>";            
        }        
        if ($error != "") {            
            $error = '<div><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' . $error . '</div>';            
        } else {

            $to = "example@gmail.com"; 
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];            
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $headers = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
                $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
            $headers = "Subject: ".$_POST['subject'] . "\r\n";
                $headers = "Message : ".$_POST['message'] . "\r\n";  

            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {                
              echo  $successMessage = '<div>Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';   
            } else {                
               echo $error = '<div><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent - please try again later</div>';                            
            }            
        }                  
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You overwrite the headers each time with `=`. You want `.=` to append to `$headers`. By the way, the message and subject should not be in the headers.

Comment: I make those changes to my code, and its working perfect now. Thank you.